# What should I worry about if I compress float64 array to float32 in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, compression

This is a particular kind of lossy compression that's quite easy to implement in numpy.

I could in principle directly compare original (float64) to reconstructed (float64(float32(original)) and know things like the maximum error.

Other than looking at the maximum error for my actual data, does anybody have a good idea what type of distortions this creates, e.g. as a function of the magnitude of the original value?

Would I be better off mapping all values (in 64-bits) onto say [-1,1] first (as a fraction of extreme values, which could be preserved in 64-bits) to take advantage of greater density of floats near zero?

I'm adding a specific case I have in mind.  Let's say I have 500k to 1e6 values ranging from -20 to 20, that are approximately IID ~ Normal(mu=0,sigma=4) so they're already pretty concentrated near zero and the "20" is ~5-sigma rare.  Let's say they are scientific measurements where the true precision is a whole lot less than the 64-bit floats, but hard to really know exactly.  I have tons of separate instances (potentially TB's worth) so compressing has a lot of practical value, and float32 is a quick way to get 50% (and if anything, works better with an additional round of lossless compression like gzip).  So the "-20 to 20" eliminates a lot of concerns about really large values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is unlikely that a simple transformation will reduce error significantly, since your distribution is centered around zero.

Scaling can have effect in only two ways: One, it moves values away from the denormal interval of single-precision values, (-2<sup>-126</sup>, 2<sup>-126</sup>). (E.g., if you multiply by, say, 2<sup>123</sup> values that were in [2<sup>-249</sup>, 2<sup>-126</sup>) are mapped to [2<sup>-126</sup>, 2<sup>-3</sup>), which is outside the denormal interval.) Two, it changes where values lie in each “binade” (interval from one power of two to the next). E.g., your maximum value is 20, where the relative error may be 1/2 ULP / 20, where the ULP for that binade is 16*2<sup>-23</sup> = 2<sup>-19</sup>, so the relative error may be 1/2 * 2<sup>-19</sup> / 20, about 4.77e-8. Suppose you scale by 32/20, so values just under 20 become values just under 32. Then, when you convert to float, the relative error is at most 1/2 * 2<sup>-19</sup> / 32 (or just under 32), about 2.98e-8. So you may reduce the error slightly.

With regard to the former, if your values are nearly normally distributed, very few are in (-2<sup>-126</sup>, 2<sup>-126</sup>), simply because that interval is so small. (A trillion samples of your normal distribution almost certainly have no values in that interval.) You say these are scientific measurements, so perhaps they are produced with some instrument. It may be that the machine does not measure or calculate finely enough to return values that range from 2<sup>-126</sup> to 20, so it would not surprise me if you have no values in the denormal interval at all. If you have no values in the single-precision denormal range, then scaling to avoid that range is of no use.

With regard to the latter, we see a small improvement is available at the end of your range. However, elsewhere in your range, some values are also moved to the high end of a binade, but some are moved across a binade boundary to the small end of a new binade, resulting in increased relative error for them. It is unlikely there is a significant net improvement.

On the other hand, we do not know what is significant for your application. How much error can your application tolerate? Will the change in the ultimate result be unnoticeable if random noise of 1% is added to each number? Or will the result be completely unacceptable if a few numbers change by as little as 2<sup>-200</sup>?

What do you know about the machinery producing these numbers? Is it truly producing numbers more precise than single-precision floats? Perhaps, although it produces 64-bit floating-point values, the actual values are limited to a population that is representable in 32-bit floating-point. Have you performed a conversion from double to float and measured the error?

There is still insufficient information to rule out these or other possibilities, but my best guess is that there is little to gain by any transformation. Converting to float will either introduce too much error or it will not, and transforming the numbers first is unlikely to alter that.

Comment: Marking as accepted.  This explains tradeoffs related to scaling (along with answer above that explained absolute and relative errors as a function of magnitude).  It seems likely that with values I care about (see example in question) I'm better off converting to float32 without any special mapping.

Answer (score 7):

The following assumes you are using standard IEEE-754 floating-point operations, which are common (with some exceptions), in the usual round-to-nearest mode.

If a double value is within the normal range of float values, then the only change that occurs when the double is rounded to a float is that the significand (fraction portion of the value) is rounded from 53 bits to 24 bits. This will cause an error of at most 1/2 ULP (unit of least precision). The ULP of a float is 2<sup>-23</sup> times the greatest power of two not greater than the float. E.g., if a float is 7.25, the greatest power of two not greater than it is 4, so its ULP is 4*2<sup>-23</sup> = 2<sup>-21</sup>, about 4.77e-7. So the error when double in the interval [4, 8) is converted to float is at most 2<sup>-22</sup>, about 2.38e-7. For another example, if a float is about .03, the greatest power of two not greater than it is 2<sup>-6</sup>, so the ULP is 2<sup>-29</sup>, and the maximum error when converting to double is 2<sup>-30</sup>.

Those are absolute errors. The relative error is less than 2<sup>-24</sup>, which is 1/2 ULP divided by the smallest the value could be (the smallest value in the interval for a particular ULP, so the power of two that bounds it). E.g., for each number x in [4, 8), we know the number is at least 4 and error is at most 2<sup>-22</sup>, so the relative error is at most 2<sup>-22</sup>/4 = 2<sup>-24</sup>. (The error cannot be exactly 2<sup>-24</sup> because there is no error when converting an exact power of two from float to double, so there is an error only if x is greater than four, so the relative error is less than, not equal to, 2<sup>-24</sup>.) When you know more about the value being converted, e.g., it is nearer 8 than 4, you can bound the error more tightly.

If the number is outside the normal range of a float, errors can be larger. The maximum finite floating-point value is 2<sup>128</sup>-2<sup>104</sup>, about 3.40e38. When you convert a double that is 1/2 ULP (of a float; doubles have finer ULP) more than that or greater to float, infinity is returned, which is, of course, an infinite absolute error and an infinite relative error. (A double that is greater than the maximum finite float but is greater by less than 1/2 ULP is converted to the maximum finite float and has the same errors discussed in the previous paragraph.)

The minimum positive normal float is 2<sup>-126</sup>, about 1.18e-38. Numbers within 1/2 ULP of this (inclusive) are converted to it, but numbers less than that are converted to a special denormalized format, where the ULP is fixed at 2<sup>-149</sup>. The absolute error will be at most 1/2 ULP, 2<sup>-150</sup>. The relative error will depend significantly on the value being converted.

The above discusses positive numbers. The errors for negative numbers are symmetric.

If the value of a double can be represented exactly as a float, there is no error in conversion.

Mapping the input numbers to a new interval can reduce errors in specific situations. As a contrived example, suppose all your numbers are integers in the interval [2<sup>48</sup>, 2<sup>48</sup>+2<sup>24</sup>). Then converting them to float would lose all information that distinguishes the values; they would all be converted to 2<sup>48</sup>. But mapping them to [0, 2<sup>24</sup>) would preserve all information; each different input would be converted to a different result.

Which map would best suit your purposes depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Re: "depends on your specific situation" are there numerical best practices?  Given that values closer to zero have smaller ULP (per above, depends on first power of 2 greater than value) the compression error is reduced but there's the error/cost with the mapping and inverting the map (64bit land), as well as some extra storage.  In the simple [-1,1] case (store extreme by-sign, map by dividing by it, invert by multiplying after upcasting) the storage requirements are tiny (assuming long array) and CPU time marginally free (compared to IO) so question is what's lost in 64bit div and mult?

Comment: It would be easier if you describe your specific situation rather than if we try to completely characterize all possible situations. Commonly, multiplying and dividing are unlikely to help much. The entire point of floating-point is to provide a dynamic range. That is, a nice scaling is already built in. Unless you are in the denormal range, relative errors vary only by a factor of two, and scaling can only reduce errors slightly. Translation can reduce errors more, but only if the domain of your numbers does not already include zero or you increase the errors in some of the domain.

Comment: Do not divide. Division is typically expensive (takes a long time to execute) on modern processors. Calculate the reciprocal once, then multiply by that. It is unlikely you need to worry about rounding errors when performing arithmetic on the double-precision numbers; the rounding errors in that arithmetic are vastly smaller than the rounding errors in converting to float. An exception is that if you have values that are exactly representable and you scale by values that are not powers of two, you may induce rounding errors where there were none before.

Comment: I added an example in the original post.

Comment: +1 for effort, I would have just http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

The exponent for float32 is quite a lot smaller (or bigger in the case of negative exponents), but assuming all you numbers are less than that you only need to worry about the loss of precision. float32 is only good to about 7 or 8 significant decimal digits

Comment: I think you're suggesting that the error as a function of magnitude is ~ (magnitude * 1e-7), up until the exponent reaches its largest values and then becomes (magnitude - max_float32)?  If that's the case and your values are small relative to max_float32, then it seems like there's nothing to be gained by trying anything fancy (like mapping values to [-1,1]) but I just want to make sure I'm interpreting correctly?  I had always heard that there were denser values near [-1,1] so I had assumed errors would be a lot smaller there.  Thx!

Comment: @JosephHastings, That's right. The values are denser but still only the same amount of precision