# Why does Tensor Flow give different results on INTEL and AMD CPUs?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was comparing floating point calculations(fp32) on AMD and INTEL CPUs. I ran the following script on Intel and AMD CPUs and observed a difference in the raw files generated by the following code snippet.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# float32 NumPy array
a = np.arange(100, dtype=np.float32)
# The same array with the same dtype in TensorFlow
a_tf = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
# Square root with NumPy
sqrt = np.sqrt(a)
sqrt.tofile('../np_exp/sqrt.raw')
# Square root with TensorFlow
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sqrt_tf = sess.run(tf.sqrt(a_tf))
    sqrt_tf.tofile('./sqrt.raw')
```

##### Script for comparing raw files:

```
import csv
import os
import argparse
import json
import numpy as np
import math
# import cv2
result_data = ''
tolrence = 0.0000001

np.set_printoptions(precision=17, suppress=True)

def csv_reader(abc1, abc2, ):
    reader1 = np.fromfile(abc1, dtype=np.float32)
    reader2 = np.fromfile(abc2, dtype=np.float32)
    #print(reader1)
    i = 0
    c = 0
    count = 0
    anti_count = 0
    isNan = 0
    try:
       for (index1, index2) in zip(np.nditer(reader1), np.nditer(reader2)):
           i = i + 1
           if math.isnan(index2):
                continue
           if abs(index1 - index2) >= tolrence:
               count = count + 1
               if count != 0:
                 print(str(index1) + " " + str(index2) + " " + str(i))
           else:
                anti_count = anti_count + 1
       if count != 0:
             print(abc1)
             print(abc2)
             print("Total Matches :  ", anti_count, "Mismatches  : ", count)

    except:
        pass
      
def list_files_from_dir(root):
    all_raw_list = list()
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            if name not in ['model.cpp', 'model.bin', 'model_net.json']:
                 all_raw_list.append(os.path.join(path, name))

    return all_raw_list


def compare_all(dir1, dir2):
    list1 = list_files_from_dir(dir1)
    list2 = list_files_from_dir(dir2)
    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        csv_reader(list1[i], list2[i])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Pushes the given JSON file onto Kibana using the Logstash path given, uses ElasticSearch')
    parser.add_argument('-i1', '--input1', help='The path to the JSON file.', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-i2', '--input2', help='The path to the JSON file.', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    input1 = args.input1
    input2 = args.input2
    compare_all(input1, input2)
```

**Note**: You can provide the folder names containing the raw files for comparision as -i1 and -i2 args to run this compare script.

The raw files (of the tf session) generated on AMD and INTEL are compared, and the difference observed is as follows:

```
1.4142135 1.4142134 3
2.0 1.9999999 5
2.4494898 2.4494896 7
2.828427 2.8284268 9
3.0 2.9999998 10
3.162278 3.1622777 11
3.6055512 3.6055508 14
4.0 3.9999998 17
4.5825763 4.5825753 22
4.6904163 4.6904154 23
4.795831 4.7958307 24
4.8989797 4.898979 25
5.099019 5.0990186 27
5.1961527 5.196152 28
5.385165 5.3851647 30
5.656854 5.6568537 33
5.7445626 5.744562 34
5.830952 5.830951 35
6.0 5.9999995 37
6.0827627 6.0827622 38
6.324556 6.3245554 41
6.557439 6.557438 44
7.0000005 6.9999995 50
7.0710683 7.0710673 51
7.2111025 7.2111015 53
7.2801104 7.280109 54
7.416199 7.4161983 56
8.0 7.9999995 65
8.062258 8.062257 66
8.124039 8.124038 67
8.306624 8.306623 70
8.42615 8.426149 72
8.5440035 8.544003 74
8.6602545 8.660254 76
9.0 8.999999 82
9.055386 9.055385 83
9.110435 9.110433 84
9.165153 9.165151 85
9.273619 9.273618 87
9.380833 9.380831 89
9.486833 9.486834 91
9.539392 9.5393915 92
9.591662 9.591661 93
9.797959 9.797958 97
9.899495 9.899494 99
9.949875 9.949874 100
./AMD/sqrt.raw
./INTEL/sqrt.raw
Total Matches :   54 Mismatches  :  46
```

(first column refers to AMD, second column refers to INTEL and third column corresponds to the i_th element in the output array that we are comparing. tolerence used for comparision is 0.0000001, i.e., the values are printed only if the difference is >= 0.0000001)

**Note**: The raw files generated by numpy sqrt computation by the above script has no difference across both the architectures. Numpy behaves similarly on INTEL and AMD.

**Steps to reproduce tf version**:

- Use tensorflow 1.15.5 (CPU version) which is built from source ( [Build from source | TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#configuration_options)).
- checkout r1.15 branch while cloning tensorflow repo
- Disable all supports during ./configure step (XLA, CUDA, etc.,).
- Provide "-march=x86-64" for --copt and --host_copt flags while doing bazel build and set --config=v1.

Can anyone please let me know whether there is a way to make tensorflow behave similarly across different CPU architectures, specifically INTEL and AMD, so that there would be no difference in the values generated on these CPUs? Please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Floating point numbers are *not* precise and suffer from scaling and rounding errors. That's why floating point numbers are never compared for equality. If you want to check whether two floats are the same, you should check whether their difference is less than a specific small threshold. You use a low-precision `float32` so it's far more likely that intermediate and final results will suffer from errors. The difference you show is in the 7th decimal digit.

Comment: What happens if you use `float64` instead?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you for the response. I didn't check with float64 because I am bound to use float32 for the work that I am doing. I was surprised considering that numpy was giving same value on both CPUs, but tensorflow isn't. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: I already explained that. Numpy and Tensorflow are different libraries, using different CPU instructions, all of which accumulate floating point errors. That's how floating point numbers work. You didn't post your actual data so it's impossible to say whether this is due to scaling (combining numbers of different scales) or rounding. Floating point numbers need to have the same scale when adding/subtracting etc. If you add very big and very large numbers, the smaller numbers get converted to the larger's scale and lose precision. The differences are *very* small and quite frankly, expected.

Comment: [The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007169/what-should-i-worry-about-if-i-compress-float64-array-to-float32-in-numpy) explain how to calculate the error for a specific floating point number. For some of the numbers you posted, the error affects the 7th digit

Comment: [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030004/test-if-two-floating-point-numbers-within-1-ulp) asks how to check if two float32 numbers are closer than 1 Unit of Least Precision, in which case they can't be compared in a meaningful way. The answer shows how to use `np.nextafter` to get the next possible float from one float, b, towards another, a. Tensorflow also has a [tf.math.nextafter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/nextafter) method

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I added the script that I used to compare the fp32 values, for reference. Did you mean, two numbers having ULP < 1 can't be compared properly and that it is inevitable? Even, if that is the case, considering that numpy isn't giving any difference, could it be because of some backend libraries(like MKL) that TF uses during these math computations which is giving these kind of errors?